Canvas not responding in QGIS
In QGIS 3.36.1 I have a weird situation as my QGIS canvas is irresponsive to layer on/off and preset theme visualization. It used to work well, but now it is unusable, even after restart.
Cache?
What can it be?
Even from the Python Console, I cannot update the canvas, e.g.:
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()


Whatever I do, like create a new vector layer and edit it, will not be shown but still there and saving edits even I do not see them while I draw them. It seems as though a fixed theme visualization prevents the canvas to update. I am lost

Is there "render" checkbox in the bottom right checked?

@bugmenot123, yes. Whatever I do, with the layers, nothing happens on the canvas. Sounds like a red flag bug to me.

Tested the same file in another windows machine, same issue - canvas stuck showing a theme without responding to my changes in the layers panel or when do any sort of editing.

So I looked into the XML version of the file and discovered this attribute that prevented any edits in the canvas. When removed by hand, all went back to normal. Not sure why/how, but editing the XML directly was the only way after deep checks.

